# Why does REGEXP_SUBSTR read certain characters ('L' and 'RD') differently than other characters

Tags: regexp-substr

I'm working with REGEXP and certain characters give unexpected results

I've tried the code below

```
WITH DATA(str) AS(
   SELECT '437 E MERRIMACK ST APT 14' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT '29 MARIAN RD # B' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT '29 MARIAN RD' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT '29 MARIAN ST' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT '104 BEECH ST # 1L'    FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'w32 IRVING RD APT M'    FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'w32 IRVING RD # L'    FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'w32 IRVING AVE'    FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT '288 N MAIN ST APT 1-4'   FROM dual
)
SELECT 
str
,REGEXP_SUBSTR(str,  '[^(APT |FL |# |$)]+$') APT 
FROM data;
```

rows 1, 2, 4, 6, 9 are fine rows 3, 5, 7, 8 do not capture the APT correctly.  It seems there is some issue with 'L' and 'RD' and 'AVE'.  I expect APT in #3 to be null, APT in #5 to be 1L, in #7 to be L and #8 to be null.

```
result# STR                         APT
1   437 E MERRIMACK ST APT 14        14
2   29 MARIAN RD # B                  B
3   29 MARIAN RD                     RD
4   29 MARIAN ST                     null
5   104 BEECH ST # 1L                null
6   w32 IRVING RD APT M              M
7   w32 IRVING RD # L                null
8   w32 IRVING AVE                VE 
9   288 N MAIN ST APT 1-4            1-4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, it doesn't, it's that your regex is wrong. you are using square brackets which describe a character class (a single character).  In your case, NOT an open paren or an A or a P or a T etc.

Try this which returns the 2nd group that follows the last occurrence of a string ending with a space then a group of either 'APT' or a pound sign then another space then anything until the end of the line (capturing the "anything" in a group). In other words, save everything after the last APT or a # and consider that the APT:

```
WITH DATA(id, str) AS (
   SELECT 1, '437 E MERRIMACK ST APT 14' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, '29 MARIAN RD # B'          FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, '29 MARIAN RD'              FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 4, '29 MARIAN ST'              FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 5, '104 BEECH ST # 1L'         FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 6, 'w32 IRVING RD APT M'       FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 7, 'w32 IRVING RD # L'         FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 8, 'w32 IRVING AVE'            FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 9, '288 N MAIN ST APT 1-4'     FROM dual
)
SELECT id, str,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(str,  '^.* (APT|#) (.*)$', 1, 1, null, 2) APT 
FROM data;

        ID STR                       APT                      
---------- ------------------------- -------------------------
         1 437 E MERRIMACK ST APT 14 14                       
         2 29 MARIAN RD # B          B                        
         3 29 MARIAN RD                                       
         4 29 MARIAN ST                                       
         5 104 BEECH ST # 1L         1L                       
         6 w32 IRVING RD APT M       M                        
         7 w32 IRVING RD # L         L                        
         8 w32 IRVING AVE                                     
         9 288 N MAIN ST APT 1-4     1-4                      

9 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks Gary_W!!  That worked with 1 minor change.  When I copied the code exactly, it didn't work -- I had to removed the extra space between the asterisk and the open parenthesis in this bit:    '^.* (APT...'       -- with that small change it works!

Comment: Sorry, I'll fix my typo.  Glad it helped you out. Please accept it as the right answer to show it worked for future searchers.